# format date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

have problem for format date in JavaScript, this is my function code

```
   //originalDate = '2016-03-02 09:12:14.989522';
   var d = new Date(originalDate),
        month = d.getMonth() + 1,
        day =d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear(),
        hour = d.getHours(),
        min = d.getMinutes();
    alert([day, month, year].join('-')+' '+[hour,min].join(':'));
```

and `my original date ='2016-03-02 09:12:14.989522';`
and my code always `return 'Nan-Nan-Nan Nan:Nan'`, It's seen unknown originalDate that I pass to. 
any help?

Note: datatype in database of date of mine is `timestamp`

Comment: The code you posted works fine, if `date` is defined correctly. You're probably not passing in the right variable to `new Date(date)`. If you paste the full code it will be more obvious what the problem is.

Comment: can you print date in the console before running these statements .. `console.log(date);`

Comment: I doubt `new Date(date)` returns valid date object..

Comment: Can you do console.log(date) at the beginning just to check if you are getting the same value you posted?

Comment: Test the `date` value given in your question, I got `"2-3-2016 9:12"`

Comment: It's working just fine http://jsbin.com/gepapaviyu/edit?js,output

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `return [day, month, year].join('-')+' '+[hour,min].join(':');`, this is not a function.

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's show ` Date {Invalid Date}` in log

Comment: @ozil yes in my code, i write it in function

Comment: @AndyRay Yes because `date` that I pass is get from database and it's  `2016-03-02 08:13:07.358598` format

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes it is. return `Invalid date`

Comment: Some commenters are saying the code in the question works fine, others saying that it does produce an error. You're all correct. The first link in my answer show that "...different ECMAScript implementations..." (which I read to mean different browsers) may parse this input acceptably, but others may parse it as a NaN error. In my browser (Firefox v44.0.2 on a Mac), the code in the question (slightly re-worked) does produce an error. (See my answer for solution.)

Comment: @AndrewWillems `date` is get from database , it's inserted by time-stamp format

Comment: @AndrewWillems yes, I just check my code with google chrom, it's worked but for Firefox , it's show `Nan`

Comment: @ching Just parse it, e.g. `date = date.replace(" ", "T");` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: Replace the space in your `date` string with a "T".

(However, to be completely technically correct, you should also include a time zone indicator at the end, either an additional "Z" to indicate UTC, i.e. Coordinated Universal Time, or "+hh:mm" or "-hh:mm" to indicate a time zone offset.)

The [MDN site for `Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) writes:

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, ...results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

and

> The date time string may be in ISO 8601 format.

The [ISP 8601 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) referred to above writes:

> The formats are as follows. Exactly the components shown here must be present, with exactly this punctuation. Note that the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

and

> Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
>   second YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)

Here is your code re-written replacing the space in `date` with a "T". If that doesn't work in your browser, add a "Z" or time zone offset at the end of `date`.

```js
var date ='2016-03-02T09:12:14.989522';
var d = new Date(date),
  month = d.getMonth() + 1,
  day = d.getDate(),
  year = d.getFullYear(),
  hour = d.getHours(),
  min = d.getMinutes();
document.write([day, month, year].join('-') + ' ' + [hour, min].join(':'));
```

Comment: Note that "just adding a T" means that where the string is parsed successfully, it will be treated as a local date, however if a "Z" as appended, it will be treated as UTC. Also, if it is a date only without a timezone, it will be treated as UTC. Otherwise, the result will be an invalid date. Just so we're clear. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is the `date` parameter in your code a `Date` object? That won't work. There is no such constructor in Javascript. You could use `date.now()` though.

Check here for the valid constructors for `Date` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: No, the `date` parameter is the questioner's code is a string, and it is (almost) valid. A direct quote from the site you linked to: `var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');` where the `'1995-12-17T03:24:00'` part is a dateString. See my answer about the use of the "T" in that string, though, which seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First parse your original date then use it in your code.

```
var MilliSecond=Date.parse(originalDate);
var d=new Date(MilliSecond),
month=d.getMonth()+1,
day=d.getDay(), .......
```

Comment: In a browser where the dateString in the original question produces an error (e.g. my browser, i.e. Firefox v44.0.2), using `Date.parse(date)` does not solve the problem, i.e. it still produces `NaN` errors everywhere.

Comment: You stated your original date as
//originalDate = '2016-03-02 09:12:14.989522';
Replace the space between date and time with letter T then parse the date string. e.g. originalDate='2016-03-02T09:12:14.989522';